# Get all session data in zend 1.12

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-auth

Hi good morning to everyone here, I have the following code which always returns me the value 'direccion' on the view, but I would like to retrieve all the values ​​of the vase of data and put it to the meeting, as I can do that, they are thank you in advance.

Controller:

```
$authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable();

$authAdapter
    ->setTableName('credential')
    ->setIdentityColumn('email')
    ->setCredentialColumn('password')
    ->setIdentityColumn('direccion');

$authAdapter
    ->setIdentity($form->getValue('email'))
    ->setCredential($form->getValue('password'))
    ->setIdentity('San marcos');
    $select = $authAdapter->getDbSelect();
            $select->where('status = "1"');

$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();

$result = $auth->authenticate($authAdapter);
```

View:

```
if (Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity()) {
    $username = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity();
    $profile = 'Welcome, ' . var_dump($username) . ' <a href="/auth/public/user/logout">logout</a>';
} else {
```

Comment: Sooo… what exactly is the question?

Comment: Hello @PatrickQ want to obtain several parameters of my database, store in session and then display them on another page.

Comment: That's not a question.

Comment: @PatrickQ this well have, How to save more than one parameter in session Zend_Auth?

Comment: Maybe I did not explain very well and I do not speak much English.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own LoginStorage class for the current user on zend_auth.
In this way, when you authenticate the user, write you LoginStorage with your custom values on Zend_auth.

Something like this:

```
<?php
//LoginStorage custom class
class LoginStorage {

public function __construct ($direccion){
     $this->direccion = $direccion;
}

public $direccion;

}
```

So when you are running auth:

```
...
if (Zend_Auth::getInstance()->authenticate($myAuthAdapter)->isValid()) {

   //Instance of UNIQUE auth -> get session writer to record authentication rowset
   Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getStorage()->write(new LoginStorage($myDireccionForThisUser));
...
```

Now, when you get `Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getStorage()->read()`, there you be a LoginStorage object ready for you.